# This python program for reminder notification slows down computer, what is wrong with the code here? I have already done pip install plyer

Tags: python, windows

I am new to python programming and was trying to make this program work which is supposed to work as a drink water windows notification reminder.

```
# importing python’s standard time utility module
import time

from plyer import notification

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        notification.notify(
            title = "**Please Drink Water Now!!",
            message ="The National Academies of Sciences, Engineering, and Medicine determined that an adequate daily fluid intake is: About 15.5 cups (3.7 liters) of fluids for men. About 11.5 cups (2.7 liters) of fluids a day for women.",
            app_icon = "C:/Users/swast/OneDrive/Desktop/pythProject/media/icon.png",
            timeout= 12
            )

time.sleep(6)
```

Whenever I try to run this program, my computer slows down for some reason and the output tab beside the terminal keeps on going while there is no notification, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't you want the `time.sleep(6)` function call to be *inside* the while loop?

Comment: You are creating infinite notifications in a tight loop with no delay, I can believe the system isn't handling it happily. Probably you want to put that sleep at the same indentation level of the notify call, to make it wait 6 seconds between the notifications?

Comment: Your sleep time (once properly indented) should be longer than the timeout value passed to notify. Check the documentation to make sure you understand what the timeout parameter does. IMHO it's badly named

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hotfix to your code as suggested:

```
# importing python’s standard time utility module
import time

from plyer import notification

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        notification.notify(
            title = "**Please Drink Water Now!!",
            message ="The National Academies of Sciences, Engineering, and Medicine determined that an adequate daily fluid intake is: About 15.5 cups (3.7 liters) of fluids for men. About 11.5 cups (2.7 liters) of fluids a day for women.",
            app_icon = "C:/Users/swast/OneDrive/Desktop/pythProject/media/icon.png",
            timeout= 12
            )

        time.sleep(6)
```

A proper way to do this would be to use a crontab to call the script at desired times. The script would call `notification.notify` only once.